# Performing an algebraic regression on syntax trees

Tags: beginner, clojure

I am quite new to Clojure and would need some advice on the following genetic programming [gist](https://gist.github.com/VojtaHavlicek/6aeb2e44b4c77e6434c0) I wrote as my first working clj program. The aim of it is to perform an algebraic regression using genetic programming on syntax trees with `+, -` and `x, 1` genes to fit \$3x + 1\$ function.

The code works, but I doubt it does so in the most elegant way available. More than understanding of the actual algorithm, I would appreciate any advice on improvement of the coding style or some shortcuts to avoid hard coding present in the code (for example, in the bracket counting in crossover function?)

```
; Algebraic regression test v.1
;
; This is a simple GP programming trial.
; Motivated by: Introduction to Genetic Programing by M. Walker

; As an example, perform a fit through the following
; set of points 3x + 1
(def to-fit '([0, 1] [1, 4]))

; The following is an implementation of Koza's growth
; Genes to use are (di-arity functions only),
; terminals are specified as expressions for simpler parsing.
(def genes {:functions ["+", "-"], :terminals ["(+ 0 1)", "(+ 0 x)"]})

;; Function to reproduce:
;; Koza's growth:
(def settings {:terminal-probability 0.3 ; probability a Koza growth node will be terminal
               :max-depth 5
               :init-population-size 100}) 

;; Recursive definition of the 2-ary growth
(defn grow-rec [depth]
  (if (and (> (rand) (:terminal-probability settings)) (< depth (:max-depth settings)))

    ; True, grow further:
    (str "(" (rand-nth (:functions genes)) \space
         (grow-rec (inc depth)) \space
         (grow-rec (inc depth)) ")" )

    ; False, stop growing
    (str (rand-nth (:terminals genes))) ; Returns the terminal
    ))

;; Recursive definition pf the 2-ary full growth
(defn full-rec [depth]
  (if (< depth (:max-depth settings))

    ; True, grow further:
    (str "(" (rand-nth (:functions genes)) \space
         (grow-rec (inc depth)) \space
         (grow-rec (inc depth)) ")" )

    ; False, stop growing
    (str (rand-nth (:terminals genes))) ; Returns the terminal

    ))

;; Fitness test?
;; TODO: convert to let syntax ?
(defn fitness-test [element]
    (def weight 0)
    (dotimes [n (count to-fit)]
      (let [point (nth to-fit n)]
        (def x (first point)) ; defined as global binding to evaluate the weight in correct context
        (def dist (- (eval (read-string element)) (last point)))
        (def weight (+ weight (* dist dist))))
      )
  {:weight weight :std-weight (/ 1.0 (+ 1.0 weight)) :expression element})

;; Genetic operations:
; Reproduction
; 10% of elements selected to survive. Selection function?

; Crossover
; 2 individuals -> new 2 individuals
; 90% of the population!
; Randomly select a subtrees from both individuals & swap

;; Select a left bracket at random:
(defn get-left-bracket-at-random [tree]
  (loop [index 0
         max-index 0
         local-male tree
         max-rand 0]

    (if (= (first local-male) \( )
      (let [r (rand)]
         (if (> r max-rand)
           (recur (inc index) index (rest local-male) r)
           (recur (inc index) max-index (rest local-male) max-rand)))

      (if (= nil (next local-male))
        max-index
        (recur (inc index) max-index (rest local-male) max-rand)
      ))))

;; Given the left bracket, get a matching right bracket
(defn get-matching-right-bracket [tree left-bracket]
  (loop [index (inc left-bracket)
         left-count 1
         right-count 0]
    (if (= left-count right-count)
      (dec index)


      (cond
       (= (nth tree index) \)) (recur (inc index) left-count (inc right-count))
       (= (nth tree index) \() (recur (inc index) (inc left-count) right-count)
       :else (recur (inc index) left-count right-count)
        ))))

;; Perform a crossover at any point in the tree
(defn crossover [male female]
  (let [male-bra (get-left-bracket-at-random male)
        male-ket (get-matching-right-bracket male male-bra)
        male-child (subs male male-bra male-ket)

        female-bra (get-left-bracket-at-random female)
        female-ket (get-matching-right-bracket female female-bra)
        female-child (subs female female-bra female-ket)]

        {:male (str (subs male 0 male-bra) female-child (subs male male-ket))
         :female (str (subs female 0 female-bra) male-child (subs female female-ket))}
    )
  )

;; Selection function: select a pair for crossover.
;; Takes a list of {:weight :std-weigth :expression} maps
(defn select-pair [fitness-tested-population
                   normalization]
  {:male (select-random fitness-tested-population normalization)
   :female (select-random fitness-tested-population normalization)}
  )

;; Selects an item at random, weighted by std. weight
(defn select-random [fitness-tested-population
                     normalization]
  (loop [index 0
         sum 0.0
         max (* (rand) normalization )
         local-fitness-tested fitness-tested-population]

    (let [next-sum (+ sum (:std-weight (first local-fitness-tested)))]
      (if (< next-sum max)
           (recur (inc index)
                  next-sum
                  max
                  (rest local-fitness-tested))

           (:expression (first local-fitness-tested))

       ))))

;; -------------------------------------------------------------
;; Algorithm loop:

;; Grow the initial population with ramped half and half method
(def population [])
(dotimes [x (:init-population-size settings)]
  (def population (conj population (full-rec (+ 1 x)))) ;; do the looping nicely?
  (def population (conj population (grow-rec (+ 1 x)))))

;; Evolve
(def to-reproduce [])
(dotimes [k 10]
  (println "Generation: " k " started!")
  ; Fitness proportionale selection
  ; Select the best 2 entries only to survive and crossover the rest
  (let [fitness-tested (map fitness-test population)
        normalization (reduce + (map :std-weight fitness-tested))
        to-reproduce (map :expression (take 10 (sort-by :weight fitness-tested)))]

        (loop [index 0
               new-generation to-reproduce
               mates (select-pair fitness-tested normalization)
               children (crossover (:male mates) (:female mates))]

          (if (< index 45) ; <-- is there any elegant way of dealing with constant multiples?
              (recur (inc index)
                     (conj new-generation (:male children) (:female children))
                     (select-pair fitness-tested normalization)
                     (crossover (:male mates) (:female mates)))

               (do
                 new-generation
                 (def population new-generation)
                 )))
    (println (first to-reproduce))))
```

Comment: Although the algebraic regression in the headline may scare the crowds, I really appreciate your edit of the question, @Jamal♦ - it makes things much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most glaring problem is abuse of `def` and `dotimes` [as previously noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64418/20251).

Rule of thumb:

- If you are calling `def` in a function body, you are doing it wrong.
- If you are redefining a variable at all, you are doing it wrong.

But as you are reassigning the vars you will not be able to convert them to `let`s. But using `reduce` you won't need temporary variables.

For example:

```
(defn fitness-test [element]
    (def weight 0)
    (dotimes [n (count to-fit)]
      (let [point (nth to-fit n)]
        (def x (first point)) ; defined as global binding ...
        (def dist (- (eval (read-string element)) (last point)))
        (def weight (+ weight (* dist dist))))
      )
  {:weight weight :std-weight (/ 1.0 (+ 1.0 weight)) :expression element})
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
(defn sum-sq-err [f to-fit]
  (let [errors (for [[x y] to-fit] (- (f x) y))]
        (reduce + (map #(* % %) errors))))

(defn make-function [exp-str]
  (eval (read-string (str "(fn [x]" element ")"))))

(defn fitness-test [element]
  (let [f (make-function element)
        weight (sum-sq-err f to-fit)]
    {:weight weight 
     :std-weight (/ 1.0 (+ 1.0 weight)) 
     :expression element}))
```

Some remarks:

- Now obtaining fitness function from the string genome (`element`) is logically separated.
- This calculation is done once, and not for each data point in the `to-fit`.
- No global var defined, no `def` abuse.
- `(eval (read-string (str "(fn [x]" element ")")))` can be equivalently written as

  ```
  (let [params '[x] body (read-string element)] (eval (list 'fn params body)))
  ```

  This version will be more useful if the names and number of parameters may change; or you start manipulating clojure lists instead of strings, you just pass in such lists as `body`.
- Problem decomposed into smaller, easy-to-understand functions.

Similarly this:

```
(def population [])
(dotimes [x (:init-population-size settings)]
  (def population (conj population (full-rec (+ 1 x)))) ;; do the looping nicely?
  (def population (conj population (grow-rec (+ 1 x)))))
```

can be rewritten as:

```
(defn make-population [size]
  (apply concat
         (for [n (range size)]
           [(full-rec (inc n)) (grow-rec (inc n))])))
```

A good rule of thumb: If it is not constant, or if it is not data it is a function. Think `defn` not `def`.

Do not make your functions depend on global vars, including settings. Use [Hollywood Principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HollywoodPrinciple) to reduce coupling between your functions.

You can break dependency of :

```
(defn grow-rec [depth]
  (if (and (> (rand) (:terminal-probability settings)) (< depth (:max-depth settings)))

    ; True, grow further:
    (str "(" (rand-nth (:functions genes)) \space
         (grow-rec (inc depth)) \space
         (grow-rec (inc depth)) ")" )

    ; False, stop growing
    (str (rand-nth (:terminals genes)))))
```

on `settings` like this:

```
(defn grow-rec [terminal-probability max-depth functions terminals depth]
  (letfn [(f [d] 
             (if (and (> (rand) terminal-probability) (< depth max-depth))
               (str "(" (rand-nth functions) \space
                    (f (inc d)) \space
                    (f (inc d)) ")" )
               (str (rand-nth terminals))))] 
    (f depth))
```

You can use [`partial`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial), if you need to convert a function that takes many configuration parameters to a function that takes fewer parameters (to pass it as an argument for example).

Style note: Never leave `)`s on a line by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `eval` is a code smell. I think you can replace your strings with nested sequences (vectors or lists) of functions. I haven't looked closely at what you're doing, but your initial set of `:terminals`

```
["(+ 0 1)", "(+ 0 x)"]
```

... would probably be replaced by

```
[(constantly 1) first]
```

... assuming all all arguments are supplied as a single sequence.

You ought to replace local `def`s with `let`s and `(dotimes [i n] ... )` with

```
(reduce (fn [a i] ... ) a-init (range n))
```

or

```
(loop [a a-init, i 0] (if (= i n) a (recur (some-form-of a i) (inc i))))
```

... but you already know that.

Comment: @vojtahavlíček There are several [genetic programming libraries at clojars.org](https://clojars.org/search?q=%28genetic+or+evolutionary%29+programming). Pick of the bunch appears to be [fungp](https://clojars.org/fungp).

Comment: I have found fungp yesterday, thanks a lot. The aim of this project was to just try the GP basics on my own -  but the approach in fungp is much neater than the string juggling I tried to do :). Great reference, thanks!

Comment: @vojtahavlíček I just found fungp today. I find the mile-long argument lists off putting: shurely shome mishtake. You've got me interested enough to have a go myself.

Comment: Good to hear that! In case you some of the code above, let me know of the results as I would like to see the thing coded properly :)